# jquery optimising hover event with div and an image

Tags: jquery, image, html, hover

code:

```
    $('.featured').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('img',this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function() {})
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('img',this).fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {})
    });
```

how can I improve this?

I recall someone telling me once not to use

`$('img', this) ..`

but I can't figure out how to access an image within the DIV being hovered over any other way.

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), like this:

```
$('.featured').hover(function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('active').find('img').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active').find('img').fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

This finds any `<img>` elements within the element you're hovering...skipping several steps `$(selector, context)` has to take to figure out it's *really* a `$(context).find(selector)` call.  Also there's no need for the animation callbacks...they're optional so just leave them off if you're doing anything in them.